# Getting started with Pico Pi controlling 5V PTC heating element 100C

Tags: noobs

I have just started with the Pico Pi and have no idea where to get info on how to power 5V 3A PTC heating element using the Pico and a MOSFET.
Would there be anyone who could give me a pointer as I have been going in circles.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70931/how-do-i-do-a-basic-mosfet-switch-with-pi may be of help. It applies to a RPi, rather than a pico, but the advice still stands. TLDR: most MOSFETs do not work well with 3.3V, so find a different solution...

Comment: What device you are using to control the unspecified element is irrelevant. The circuitry would be the same regardless of controller.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers, thank you

Comment: This might help: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/b45c4a7snvv9/irl540n_2023feb0103/

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a MOSFET with Pico (or Pi) GPIO; use a bipolar transistor.

*Why?* RPi and Pico GPIOs switch between Gnd & 3.3V; most MOSFETs need a higher gate-source voltage than that to reduce the drain-source resistance. The MOSFETs that do operate as a proper switch at 3.3V gate-source generally come with tradeoffs that are undesirable in prototypes & hobbyist construction. For example:

- They often come in [tiny packages](https://www.vishay.com/docs/63894/si8424cdb.pdf) designed for surface-mount construction techniques.
- In general, MOS devices are more vulnerable to ESD-induced failures due to handling and *unplanned events*.

If one is building a performance-critical, production prototype  device, there may be strong incentives to use low-V<sub>gs</sub> MOSFETs in a Raspberry Pi project. But there are tradeoffs associated with most all decisions; e.g. ease-of-use & component ruggedness vs better performance. As your question is currently worded, you're better-suited to make those tradeoffs than we are.

OTOH, there are numerous bipolar Darlingtons that will handle your 5V, 3A load:

- 2N6040−2N6045 Series,
- [TIP120−TIP122](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/tip122-d.pdf) Series,
- TIP125−TIP127 Series

With a (typical) DC Current Gain (h<sub>FE</sub>) of 2000 or higher, one of these Darlingtons can efficiently switch 3A with a tiny 1.5 mA source current from the GPIO - well within their range. They are available in "leaded" packages (e.g. [TO-220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220), etc) for easy breadboard construction, and fairly cheap (<$1 USD last I checked).

A heating element can be driven with a "low side" switch arrangement as shown below.

You can find data sheets online for the Darlington devices listed above. Let us know if you have questions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnlmJY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly the nudge I needed to get started. Thank you

Comment: @ColinThomson: Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a MOSFET, a darlington will lose about 1.4V when saturated leaving you 5-1.4V = 3.6V for the heater. A MOSFET will have a much lower drop. Look at the Si8424DB, Si8424DB, RFP30N06LE as a starting point. There are many others that will do more current with more becoming available every week.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running a rp for at least 7 years 24/7/365 as a radius server. It is on stable power and running headless.
Other than clearing the log files once in a while and blowing off the dust, that's all I need to do.
I do complete backups of the data every night.